# how can we observe specific changes made to SQLDeLight DB and emit them?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kmm, sqldelight

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE Missions(
    MissionID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    MilestoneID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    MissionExpiry TEXT,
    MissionStatus TEXT,
    Count INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    MilestoneList TEXT,
    UpdatedTime TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY (MissionID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_milestone FOREIGN KEY(MilestoneID)  REFERENCES Milestone(MilestoneID)
);
```

I want to emit an event whenever the count attribute gets updated in the above table.

I have written a query like this:

```
Val allItems: Flow<List<Item>> =
ItemQueries.selectAll().asFlow().mapToList()
```

But the flow is triggering whenever there is insertion or updation on any attribute inside the table and all rows are getting fetched. I want to fetch only the rows that are updated not all rows. How can I get it done?